# splice doesn't change the length of the array

Tags: javascript

JavaScript array.splice alters the length of an array. But the following code always seems to pull the first 10 elements of the array without change it's length. This throws it into an infinite loop. What's wrong?

```
files = ['a','b','c',....]; // 100 elements
while( files.length ){
    files = files.splice( 0, 10 );
    console.log( files );
}
```

Comment: `splice` returns the removed elements, and changes the array in place. Your assignment is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `splice` return an array containing the deleted elements and then you again assign that to `files`. Hence the `files` array has always 10 values and condition is never false. You can just use it like:

```
files = ['a','b','c',....]; // 100 elements
while( files.length ){
    files.splice( 0, 10 );
    console.log( files.length );
    //=> 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0
    // after that it will get out of this loop
}
```

Remember, the `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements. So, if you need `files` for further processing then keep that values in a temporary array first and then use that temp array with `splice()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had seen it work without the assignment and the I kept banging my head and it was pretty stupid. Unfortunately js documentation is not as robust as php (personal opinion). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with you assigment.Just remove it because `splice` alter the array in place.and it return the removed elements that you are assigning back to array

```js
files = ['a','b','c','a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']; // 100 elements
while( files.length ){
    files.splice( 0, 10 );
    console.log( files );
}
```